# Problem with spring neo4j hydrating related List of nodes using custom query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

My custom query using @Query annotation is not hydrating the related nodes that are returned for each parent node.

Entity

```
public class Dater implements CSVFormat{
    @Id
    private String userId;
    private String gender;
    private String postalCode;
    private int age;
    @Relationship(type = "LISTENS_TO")
    //polymorphic set pointing to various interface implementations
    private Set<PersistentDaterMusicItem> musicItems = new HashSet<>();
    ...//partially left out for brevity
}
```

Query

```
@Query("MATCH (user:Dater { userId:  $userId })-[:LISTENS_TO]->(musicItems)<-[mr:LISTENS_TO]-(matches:Dater) "
            + "where id(user) <> id(matches) "
            + "RETURN matches, collect(mr), collect(musicItems) ")
    List<Dater> getMatches(String userId);
```

Caller

```
List<Dater> daters = daterRepository.getMatches(id);
```

The daters list contains 2 Dater objects which is correct but the musicItems field has 0 items. The cypher query works fine when executed directly returning multiple relationships and related nodes per parent Dater node.

Spring neo4j version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I am trying to populate a list of PersistentDaterMusicItem which is an interface and the label I am assigning to the node in neo4j db are the class names of the concrete implementations of PersistentDaterMusicItem
like Song, Artist, etc. Since these don't match there is not hydration.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it does not map the application entities because it cannot find anything to map PersistentDaterMusicItem to in the database. Since that entity is an abstract for specific items, you can create subentities in your application for Song, Artist, etc and have each extend the PersistentDaterMusicItem class. That should help Spring know what to map in the database. I have a similar setup in a [code repository](https://github.com/JMHReif/sdn-jdk-versions/blob/gerrits-playground/src/main/java/com/jmhreif/sdnjdkversions/domain/Delta.java) on Java versions for a Delta class that can be an Enum, Annotation, Field, etc.